# Identify multiple row instances in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

There are some data in an excel file for which I have made a pivot table. In the attached example, there are some labels viz. **Data 1** & **Data 3** which have multiple values unlike the others which have unique ones. 
I need to filter or sort the data in the pivot such that these multiple instance ones are visible together for easy identification.

[image]

Comment: put Data in your Row labels and put SUM of labels in your values, DO NOT Value into your rows

Comment: @PeterH: I didn't get that. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses! I figured it out.
So as per the example and attached screenshot, I added the Label1 (Data) in Rows, Label2 (Values) in Columns and then Label2 in Values. So this got me the bifurcation of the Grand Total which I then took below the pivot table so as to take the Counts of the Values (Column marked orange - Instances). Then I sorted them descending so as to whichever Labels had more than 1 count.

[image: Solved]

Comment: this is what I meant in my original comment, you do not need to have Label 2 in the columns section, the count will work without it, I called it data, as I did not know the heading name

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a 2nd pivot table with the same data, But have the Values filtered first then the Data?

[image]

Comment: Not done that, but how will that help?

Comment: I've added an image to my post, this will show you that Value 2 is in Data1 and Data3. I may have misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: Yea, so you have adjusted the labels order. I want the data such that whichever Label1 values have multiple Label2 values, those can be able to filtered out specifically or sorted ascending that they may appear first. Hope I clarified the statement